# why is addEventListener not working on datalist?

Tags: javascript

HTML

```
<input type="text" list="countries" name="mycountry" />
<datalist id="countries">
  <option value="India">India</option>
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
  <option value="France">France</option>
</datalist>
```

JS

```
var a  = document.getElementById('countries') ;
a.addEventListener('change', function () {alert(this.value) ;} , false) ;
```

I want when list's option will select than alert box show that value .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind listener to the input element

```js
var a = document.getElementsByName('mycountry')[0];
a.addEventListener('change', function() {
  alert(this.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" list="countries" name="mycountry" />
<datalist id="countries">
  <option value="India">India</option>
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
  <option value="France">France</option>
</datalist>
```